# iFrame changes are disappearing once the script leaves the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a function that searches the html of an iFrame for a word and makes it red. It does the job correctly until it leaves the function and then the changes are reverted.

```
$('#searchContent').on('click', 'a.generated', function() {
    $('#searchResults').hide();
    $('#iFrame1').show();

    var textArry = document.getElementById('iFrame1').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('iFrame1').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = textArry.replace("your new", "<span style='color: red;'>your new </span>");
});
```

Looking in the development tools it stays red until the last bracket then reverts as soon as it leaves. Just confused about what could possibly be causing this to happen.

Comment: Well, you are clicking an `<a>` tag.  Are you sure there isn't a page transfer going on?

Comment: If the link targets the iframe, sure.

Comment: That was it thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question Answered, Taplar pointed out that i was using a  tag which was causing the refresh!